# GWT FIFO ordered queue or list?

Tags: java, gwt, queue

Is there a Queue or List in GWT in which items are retrieved in the order in which they were added?

E.g I want to be able to do this:

```
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");

for (String s: list)
{
   Window.alert( s);
}
```

and for the output to always say: `a, b, c` and never `c, a, b` or any other order. Is that possible?

I see on the [JRE emulation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) page that PriorityQueue is implemented, however the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) for that says that the items are ordered in their natural order. I'm not sure what exactly that means, if it means FIFO (first in first out), or some other way of ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natural Order Means that they are sorted based on the default [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Try using a [Linked List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Comment: Is LinkedList fifo ordered?

Comment: Yes, you can add and remove the head and end efficiently.

Comment: what about `while (! linkedList.isEmpty() ) linkedList.removeFirst()` ? Will that be ordered?

Comment: Yes, if you use linkedList.add(E e), and linkedList.removeFirst(), it will have the insertion order you desire

Comment: As would any other List in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You get this guarantee with any [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), including [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). I recommend an ArrayList as it is generally a good idea to use specific implementations in GWT to reduce serialization code. LinkList is another option, and there is a good comparison when to use it instead of ArrayList: [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist?rq=1)

Comment: List - An ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list each element is inserted. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: It is an order in which elements are inserted. Look at the JavaDoc for ArrayList - add(E e) adds an element to the end of the list.